# While loop with unary operator alone?

Tags: c

How does the value of `i` change while the loop iterates, in the below?
I have been unable to understand whether the loop condition will change the value of I or whether it will just check it and let it pass along.

```
void main()
{
    int i = 31;
    while (i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            i = i / 2;
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            continue;
        else
            i = i - 2;
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `i++` will change i value

Comment: It will do both - check the condition and then advance i

Comment: to solve this for yourself, put `printf("%d\n",i);` at the start of the loop

Comment: Equivalent to `for( i = 31; i != 0; i++ )`

Comment: @Clifford Not quite, the first iteration of the loop has `i == 32`

Comment: @M.M : Oh yes; good point.  Nasty code in any case - not something perhaps a novice should be studying to learn from, unless it is to learn how not to write code.

Comment: Why did you not just printf it out at the top of the loop?  Why take the time to ask such a question here?

Answer (score 1):

In C Programming, `0` is `false`, while non zero numbers like 1, -1, etc are `true`.

You may try this code snippet to understand how conditions are evaluated:

```
int result1 = (4 > 6);  // 0
int result2 = (3 != 6); // 1
```

syntax of while loop:

```
while(<condition>){ // evaluates either 0 or 1
   // body of loop
}
```

In your code:

```
while(i++) // initial value of i is 31, hence it is evaluated as true.
```

Also with post increment operator `i++`, value of `i` keeps on increment by 1 on each pass. This loop will break/quit only if `i` is 0(zero).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trace-through:

```
On loop 1, i = 32:
```

Multiple of 2? (Yes: i = 16).    Multiple of 3? (No: i = 14, print i)

```
On loop 2, i = 15:
```

Multiple of 2? (No: no change).  Multiple of 3? (Yes: no change, no print)

```
On loop 3, i = 16:
```

Multiple of 2? (Yes: i = 8).  Multiple of 3? (No: i = 6, print i)

```
On loop 4, i = 7:
```

Multiple of 2? (No: no change).  Multiple of 3? (No: i = 5, print i)

```
On loop 5, i = 6:
```

Multiple of 2? (Yes: i = 3).  Multiple of 3? (Yes: no change, no print)

```
On loop 5, i = 4:
```

Multiple of 2? (Yes: i = 2).  Multiple of 3? (No: i = 0, print i)

Stop looping because i = 0.

Printouts: 14, 6, 5, 0

Comment: after loop1, the value becomes 16. so in loop 2 shouldnt it become 17?

Comment: @YashNaik: No, after loop one, the value is 14.  After the increment in the loop condition for iteration 2 of the loop, the value is 15 at the start of the body of the loop, as detailed in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

It will first check the value of `i`, and after that advance it by 1.
If you would have typed `while(++i)`, it would of updated the value of `i` first and then checked it.

In your particular case this doesn't matter much, just so you know...

Comment: The use of `++i` vs `i++` does matter a lot — with the first, the loop stops when `i` is `-1` before the condition is evaluated, while with the second, the loop stops when `i` is `0` before the condition is evaluated.  That's a significant difference most of the time.